# Objective C: "Open in" dialogue in Safari should show my app as an option

Tags: ios

I've looked a long time here on Stackoverflow and in the internet, but didn't find a real answer. I want in Safari on the iPhone if you click the arrow that in the "Open in" dialogue my app is displayed. And then the HTML file or whatever should be opened in my app. How can I achieve that? If you have a step by step example, that would be great...

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate to the OS the document types that your application can open. To do this you add a Uniform Type Identifier to your app’s Info.plist for each document type that it knows about.  See Apple’s Technical Q&A 1587 - [How do I get my application to show up in the Open in... menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html).